# read gsm number from iphone through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, phone-number

Is it possible through javascript to read the number from the iphone.
Lets say i have a html page where they have to fill in the gsm number, can javascript read the number from the phone and fill the form with it?

Comment: Java doesn't work on the iPhone, so how would you retrieve the phone number?! The only way to read the phone numbers is to write a native application for iPhone and then send the number on a webview using the javascript.

Comment: my bad i should have written javascript, i wil modify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From JavaScript, it's not possible. Actually, the iPhone itself might not know it at all, as the phone number is not necessarily stored on your SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that if you are writing your own iPhone application, you can use following:

1. UIWebView class: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html
2. You can have HTML code in the your application bundle (or just anywhere on the web)
3. You can execute any Javascript on that HTML using this method: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW21

Answer (score 0):

There is a Draft from W3C on [System Information API into the Device API](http://www.w3.org/2009/05/DeviceAPICharter.html) section. But it is not yet implmented in any browser.