# how to fetch contacts on iphone with html5 and js

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

is there any way to fetch contacts on iphone with user permission via html5 and js? I know app can reach that data but browser can also too?

Comment: There's no way to do this I'm afraid. The only way to access contact on an iPhone is to write an app.

Comment: This has been asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738243/get-users-number-from-iphone-using-html5-jquery

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know a web app is restricted to a sandbox within Safari, and it does not (yet) have an API to support this.

Although there are in between solutions, semi-native apps which provide you with a framework that have an API for this, which you can access with js queries. An example of this is [Phone gap](http://phonegap.com/)