# Get user's mobile number with html or javascript, without using native or hybrid mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ios

I want to find the mobile number of the user who is browsing my website through mobile browser.

Is it possible to do it with HTML or javascript or is there any javascript or jquery library available for it??

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738243/get-users-number-from-iphone-using-html5-jquery

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you are getting mobile number of the user browsing your website until and unless you ask user for mobile number i.e. textfield to enter.